# Question of regular open

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

A set $U$ in a topological space $X$ is called regular open if $U=\text{Int}\left(\overline{U}\right)$. Similarly, a set $F$ is regular closed if $X\setminus F$ is regular open or equivalently $F=\overline{\text{Int}(U)}$.

If $A\subseteq X$. Shows $U(A)$ is regular open. Where $U(A)=\bigcup\{U \space \text{open} :U\Vdash A\}$

A suggestion for this exercise, I have had many problems with this fact. Thanks

Comment: $U(A)=\cup\{U \text{ open}\mid A\subseteq U\}$?

Comment: @QuiqueRuiz: I suspect that you’re right about the union, but given the [tag:descriptive-set-theory] tag, $U\Vdash A$ probably means that $A$ is co-meagre in $U$. The OP does need to confirm, though.

Comment: Hello Brian M. Scott, I want it no solutions just a suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HINT: First prove that $U(A)\Vdash A$. Then show that $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}U(A)\Vdash U(A)$, and conclude that $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}U(A)\Vdash A$. It may be useful to recall that a set is co-meagre in $V$ if and only if it contains the intersection of countably many dense open subsets of $V$.